# Estimator bias without a closed form?

Tags: probability, estimation, mathematical-statistics, optimization, bias

Given a regression loss function $l(Z,\beta)=||Y-Z\beta||_2 + \lambda \beta^TD\beta + r(X,Z)$ where $X$ is the predictor matrix, I would like to estimate a $Z$ that minimizes the above loss in a regression setting. $D$ is a fixed matrix similar to the setting in ridge regression, but $r(.)$ is non-convex.

How can I estimate the bias of the minimizer $\hat{\beta}$, especially because, I only have iterative updates that converge to a minimum, and do not have a closed form for both $\hat{\beta}, \hat{Z}$?

On the whole my iterative updates have this structure:

$Z_n=f(\beta_{n-1})$

$\beta_n=g(Z_{n-1},\beta_{n-1})$

How do I compute   $\mathbb{E}(\beta_n)$ as $n \to \infty$? This confuses me! But I can vouch for $||\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}||$ converging to $0$ for some, $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Apart from the question of computing the bias or approximating an estimate for the bias, what are the theoretical/empirical strategies I can use to measure the quality of my estimator?

Comment: This question is rather broad. Much of the information in it appears irrelevant: what matters is that you have an estimator $(\hat{X}, \hat{\beta})$ of $(X,\beta)$ and you would like to know of methods to evaluate it that do not use a simple or closed formula for $(\hat{X},\hat{\beta})$. So, in effect, you are asking for a general treatise on statistical estimation. To narrow your question, could you tell us about the actual problem you face?

Comment: @whuber, I edited/posed the problem am facing. Would you prefer that I put forth the distributional assumptions? I'd like to see your perspectives, as my issue is concerned with the lack of a closed-form. But, there may be a different view, on the problem of estimating the bias..that is not concerned with the lack of a closed form?

Comment: My point is that the lack of a closed form changes very little about the questions you ask. There is nothing in the theory of estimation that supposes there is a closed form (and frequently there is not--consider Maximum Likelihood estimation for all but the simplest textbook situations, for instance)--so literally every bit of it applies here. For all we know, your iteration is computing an MLE, or it could be computing some other estimator. Without having information about your circumstances, there's little anyone can offer to help apart from broad generalities.

Comment: Agreed. Will edit right now, to put in information about my estimator, followed by the distributional assumptions I make. Likewise, I have been wondering if you can put in a pointer to a paper with an iterative scenario where the expectation of the estimator is computed within a regression setting? I agree there are many such cases from 'REML' to Alternating Least Squares to M-estimation and so on and so forth. I would like a pointer to a paper that covers this scenario.

Comment: Do you mean that the *expectation* is computed iteratively or that the *estimator itself* is computed iteratively? Usually the expectation is computed theoretically in a way independent of any numerical techniques used to obtain estimators for actual datasets.

Comment: Only the 'estimator' is computed iteratively. The theoretical part you mention is what is of interest to me. I need a starting point or example in this direction of computing expectations for an iterative update or some theoretical setting regardless of the iteration, that checks for the bias. It is even fine, if someone had a naive iterative algorithm for estimating the beta's in a linear regression ;) though we know that the OLS estimator is the same as MLE. But if there was an iterative estimation, how would the unbiasedness of $\hat{\beta}$ be verified? ;)